# OnPointerEnter() function not working properly

Tags: c#, user-interface, debugging, unity-game-engine

I am creating an inventory system in Unity, and I have been baffled by a troublesome enigma. The OnMouseEnter function fails to execute when I drag the item in my inventory system back to previous slots. I have used the Control Double keyboard short cut to create three slots. They are named "Slot", "Slot(1)", and "Slot2". **When I drag my item to Slot(1), I can't drag it back to the first slot, "Slot". When I drag my item to Slot(2), I can't drag it to my second slot, "Slot(1)".** I have noticed that the OnPointerEnter() method does not get called when I try to drag the item from "Slot(2)" to "Slot(1)" or "Slot". Why is that?

This inventory moving script is supposed to work by **setting the parent of the item to the slot that the mouse is dragging to and then positioning it to Vector3.Zero in local position**. The InventoryController script is attached to the **UIImage**, inventory, the SlotController script is attached to the **UIImage**, Slot, and the Item script is attached to the **UIImage**, Item. My Hierarchy, Inspector, and Scripts are below in images. Thank you for helping me in advanced!

[image: Item Script]

[image: SlotController Script]

[image: InventoryController Script]

[image: Game View]

Comment: I think you should only start dragging (`OnBeginDrag`) if you have an item selected. Don't simply set `controller.dragging = true`. Also, you don't need that bool in `SlotController`. Just access `controller.dragging` directly. Using update to check the bool might cause a problem where the bool wasn't updated when you check it in `OnPointerEnter`.

Answer (score 0):

Well I can see you are getting a null reference exception in OnEndDrag. do a check if the controller object has a reference.

Comment: I am no longer getting the null reference exception, but I am still unable to move my items back to their original slots @UriPopov